# FC3 - NVIDIA 1050 - Distant texture color in sepia

Tags: far-cry-3, nvidia-geforce-experience

Game: Far Cry 3
GPU: NVidia GeForce 1050

From last couple of days, object at a distance(Except sky) is rendering in a sepia color! I don't remember about changing any graphics settings on game or graphics card.

[image: Far Cry 3 - NVidia - Distant texture sepia color]

I tried restoring default brightness/contrast/gamma values in calibration menu, but it did not work out. Also reset optimal settings for FC3 in GeForce Experience application.
Does anybody know about any settings that can revert this effect?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally turned on color blind mode?

Comment: Does this only happen in Far Cry 3?

Comment: @SPYBUG96 Is there any settings for color blind mode? Please note that only distant objects are in this color! When I go near them, they will show up in actual color.

Comment: @RoijanEskor Yes, other games are older ones, runs in DirextX9 :P

Comment: I found this thread that looked similar. https://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/756706-Far-Cry-3-Graphic-Problem-Forums

Comment: The files the last poster mention are located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Far Cry 3\data_win32\

Comment: That did not work out either. Thanks for the link.